# Which assembly code run faster

Tags: assembly

[A]:

```
mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax

add    $0x3,%rax

mov    %rax,-0x10(%rbp)
```

[B]

```
addq   $0x3,-0x18(%rbp)
```

Could you tell me [A] or [B] run faster?

basically [A] make use of register and [B] doesn't.

Or maybe [B]'s code actually use register too? I really cannot figure out.

BTW by experiment the results show that [B] run faster than [A]

Comment: Sounds like you already answered your question.

Comment: If you don't need to re-use the value, [B] will almost certainly be faster. But you should always benchmark, because CPUs are complex.

Comment: @Mysticial I find I will get different result on different hardware...

Comment: That doesn't change anything. You ran it on different hardware and got different results. So the answer to you question is, "it depends on the hardware".

Comment: @Jianchen On what hardware A was faster than B?

Comment: Also ... more context please. A benchmark, even a micro-benchmark, contains code-to-be-tested as well as the measuring framework; do you profile invocation in a loop ? do you read TSC pre/post ? What (and how) do you measure ?